# How to fix nextbot on Garry's Mod (non steam)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Can you help me fix the error in the Garry's Mod (.lua) file.

I installed the nextbot mod and when I click spawn it shows me "something is creating script errors".
As I approach, he suddenly kills me, but is invisible and makes no sound

```
                        Here is the command:
```

```
[ERROR] lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:187: trying to call "GetNavAreaCount" field (empty)
       1. v - addons/ungalia [nextbot]/lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:187
        2. Call - lua/includes/modules/hook.lua:82
         3. Spawn_NPC - game modes/sandbox/gamemode/commands.lua:438
          4. unknown - gamemodes/sandbox/gamemode/commands.lua:464
           5. unknown - lua/includes/modules/concommand.lua:69
```

```
                               Or:
```

```
[ERROR] lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:143: trying to call "GetAllNavAreas" field (empty)
       1. buildHidingSpotCache - addons/ungalia [nextbot]/lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:143
        2. OnReloaded - addons/ungalia [nextbot]/lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:422
         3. unknown - addons/ungalia [nextbot]/lua/entities/npc_ungalia.lua:412
          4. Spawn - [C]:-1
           5. InternalSpawnNPC - gamemodes/sandbox/gamemode/commands.lua:400
            6. Spawn_NPC - game modes/sandbox/gamemode/commands.lua:433
             7. unknown - gamemodes/sandbox/gamemode/commands.lua:464
              8. unknown - lua/includes/modules/concommand.lua:69
```

**Please reply as soon as possible.**

Comment: Garry's Mod is *only* on steam, what do you mean by non-steam? Pirated?